# Tkinter PhotoImage Put Method Transparency (on Canvas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to create semi-transparent 1x1 images which I can zoom on the canvas.
Currently, I have a directory full of prerendered transparent images for each possible alpha value, however I would like to avoid that.

Also, I cannot use anything outside of the standard library - this is for a school project and the computers don't have admin access (cannot use PIP).

Using PhotoImage, you can create a blank image and place pixels in the desired coordinates, however when specifying the color used, I can't figure out how to pass in alpha values. The Tcl Tk documentation (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/photo.htm#M53) states you can specify alpha values in colors.

From my understanding, a red color with an alpha value of 0.5 would look like this: `#ff0000@0.5`

Here's the code I have right now:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500, bg = "black", highlightthickness = 0)
canvas.pack()

image = tk.PhotoImage(width = 1, height = 1)
image.put("#ff0000@0.5", (0, 0))
image = image.zoom(30)

canvas.create_image(
    0,
    0,
    image = image,
    anchor = "nw"
)

root.mainloop()
```

Can I place transparent pixels/regions using the put method in Tkinter's PhotoImage? **I cannot use PIL.**

Comment: Pick on from [`[python][tkinter] PhotoImage transparency`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+PhotoImage+transparency)

Answer (score 0):

`transparent = "#000000"` # color that will be considered as "transparent"

```
if color != transparent:
    image.put(color, (0, 0))
```